# How to Upload Dropshipper Provided Images

Tags: zen-cart

My dropshipper has provided me with a zip folder that contains images of their products in jpeg format. I am using Zen Cart version 1.5 and am not sure how to proceed. Do I just need to upload these image files to my root directory's image folder? Do I need to do anything to the database? Do I need a install a module to have these products added or do I have to add each product one by one manually through the backend? Is anyone able to point me in the right direction on this? Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Look at a Zen Cart Addon called Easy Populate. Once set up it will be easier for you to keep the dropship products up to date. It is basically importing products (including image paths) to Zen Cart from a spreadsheet.